# How to find white/ black pixels between 2 points javacv

Tags: opencv, pixel, javacv

How can I find white/black pixels between 2 points in javacv? I have tried with cvInitLineIterator but I don't know if I am on the right way..
Many thanks for considering my request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Convert your image data into grayscale
- Get list of pixels between your two points using `cvInitLineIterator`
- Now verify each pixel value in line. 0 is ideally black (#000000) and your max pixel depth value is white.

I think you are moving in a right direction.

Comment: Why HSL? Grey should be enough. Grey is basically same as L, iirc.